# Alias of a template. Who's right?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following code seems reasonable, but doesn't work on two major compilers

```
#include <type_traits>

template<template<class> class Tmp>
struct S{
    template<class T>
    using tmp_t = Tmp<T>;

    static_assert(std::is_same_v< S<tmp_t>, S<Tmp> >,
        "Not same?? How come?");
};

template<class> struct Dummy{};

template struct S<Dummy>;
```

*gcc* starting with *7.1* compiles alright ( https://godbolt.org/z/DjAcgP )

*clang* ( https://godbolt.org/z/ewBbZJ )
and
*msvc* ( https://godbolt.org/z/6ZmQwj )
fail to do so

Is this code standard conformant?

Comment: [CWG 1286](http://wg21.link/cwg1286)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC is wrong. `tmp_t` declares a new template (an alias template to be precise). And this new template is distinct from any other template.

> **[temp.alias]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.alias#1) A template-declaration in which the declaration is an
>   alias-declaration declares the identifier to be an alias template. An
>   alias template is a name for a family of types. **The name of the
>   alias template is a template-name**.

The text in bold means that `tmp_t` refers to the new alias template, it does not refer to whatever the alias' specializations may be defined as. As such `S<tmp_t>` and `S<Tmp>` are two specializations with *different* arguments.

To contrast, there are special rules that make alias template specializations stand in for the exact thing they alias

> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.alias#2) When a template-id refers to the specialization of an alias
>   template, it is equivalent to the associated type obtained by
>   substitution of its template-arguments for the template-parameters in
>   the type-id of the alias template.

So the while template-id `tmp_t<foo>` means exactly the same thing as `Tmp<foo>`, `tmp_t` itself (without arguments) is not a template-id (it does not name a specialization). Instead it names the template, a different entity.

Comment: And what about infinite recursion? Before instantiating `std::is_same`, `S<tmp_t>` should be instantiated, then `S<tmp_t>` again and so on...

Comment: @Evg - I'm not sure it needs to be instantiated. `S<tmp_t>` is the type name, and the way it is used does not appear to me as requiring a complete class definition. By that token, it should not really be recursively instantiated. I base this on https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#1

Comment: so there's no way I can get the template `Tmp` given a specialization of `S`... that's a bummer. I was thinking of a converter class that has _source_ and _destination_ parameters, but I guess I'll have to dig in another direction.

Comment: @Adler - I'm afraid so. I'm not aware of any way to expose `Tmp` itself up for manipulation.

Comment: I have to trust you becaue my standardese is far too low to get to the same conclusion from the parts you are quoting. By any chance, do you know if there is a bug report on that? Actually, now that I know the answer, I dont consider it as a serious bug, because when the correct answer is "no" then anyhow there isnt much useful one can do with comparing a template with an ailas template.

Comment: @idclev463035818 - I believe https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92060 is the one.

Comment: actually [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1286) from the comment above suggests that there are / were considerations to make gcc's the correct behavior. have to do some research to know what happened to that proposal