# Using typealias in place of typedef defined in class in definition

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-bug

Why does this fail to compile?  I am trying to reduce the amount of repetition since in the real code the class name is huge and the `type` is actually a very long name

https://godbolt.org/z/8YarWs

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct S {
    using type = std::vector<T>;

    type f() const;
};

template<typename T>
using type_t = typename S<T>::type;

template <typename T>
type_t<T> S<T>::f() const { }
```

The code above fails as below

```
<source>:17:14: error: no declaration matches 'type_t<T> S<T>::f() const'
   17 | type_t < T > S < T >::f() const
      |              ^~~~~~~
<source>:8:10: note: candidate is: 'S<T>::type S<T>::f() const'
    8 |     type f() const
      |          ^
<source>:4:8: note: 'struct S<T>' defined here
    4 | struct S
      |        ^
```

Comment: Note that any instantiation of your template will violate [\[basic.def.odr\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#1), as you have multiple definitions of `f()` for each set of tempate arguments (/each specialization of `S`). Did you mean to only _declare_ `f()` in the class definition? Either way this is red herring and it seems like you've found a GCC bug (clang compiles the corrected example).

Comment: I keep encountering this bug as well, I suspect it has something to do with gcc treating type aliases as an intermediate representation. Clang compiles this fine: https://godbolt.org/z/aYYM3c
Note: you could also just deal with this in gcc by declaring f like so: `type_t<T> f() const;`

Comment: As a work-around, you can use `auto S<T>::f () const -> type` (trailing return type).

Comment: Thanks for fixing the in class declaration

Comment: I had to write a C++11 compatible type trait to check if two template classes were instantiations of the same template (like: `S<T>` and `S<U>`). However, it seemed that whenever when used with an alias like: `template <typename T> using V = S<T>`, all my asserts would fail, unless I compared their results (i.e. the two templates weren't equal, but the type result of what they yielded in a `decltype` were). Odd that it's existed for over 5 major revisions, but to be fair it's little more than an annoyance.

Comment: @jfh I also ran into the exact problem that you're describing, but that behavior turned out to be correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58782399/alias-of-a-template-whos-right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a GCC bug; the closest<sup>(1)</sup> confirmed open bug report seems to be:

- [Bug 69348:](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69348) alias declarations can not be used inside qualifiers of declarators

which highlights that GCC rejects the following well-formed program:

> ```
> template <class T>
> struct X {
>     int foo();
> };
>
> template <class T>
> using foo2 = X<T>;
>
> template <class T>
> int foo2<T>::foo()
> {
> }
> ```

with the error message

> ```
> error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct X<T>'
> ```

---

<sub>(1) Scanning GCC:s bugzilla, there seems to be numerous "rejects valid" (open/unconfirmed) bug reports relating to alias templates, where in most reports clang is reported to accept the (arguably well-formed) example programs.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember the exact reason why, but I know it has something to do with the sequence in which the compiler resolves the type names and symbols...
You could get it to work by changing a bit the structure of the declaration.

Since I don't know how much of this is possible for you, I included some variants.

https://godbolt.org/z/bGPGhW

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct S
{
    using type = std::vector<T>;

    auto f() const -> decltype(type());
    auto g() const -> decltype(type()); 
    decltype(type()) h() const;
};

template <typename T>
using type_t = typename S<T>::type;

template <typename T>
auto S<T>::f() const -> decltype(type())
{
    std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    type_t<T> t;
    return t;
}

template <typename T>
using other_type_t = decltype(typename S<T>::type());

template <typename T>
auto S<T>::g() const -> other_type_t<T>
{
    std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
    other_type_t<T> t;
    return t;
}

template <typename T>
using last_type_t = decltype(typename S<T>::type());

template <typename T>
last_type_t<T> S<T>::h() const
{
    std::cout << "foobar" << std::endl;
    last_type_t<T> t;
    return t;
}

int main(){
    S<int> s;
    auto t = s.f();
    auto r = s.g();
    auto l = s.h();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Program returned: 0
Program stdout

foo
bar
foobar
```